# Cannot apply material to a *.obj in away3d

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, away3d

I cannot apply a texture to an object, I don't know why...

***( AS3 blender export script and Collada Import is not working for me
either )***

Any idea?

```
var loader:Loader3D = new Loader3D(); 
loader.addEventListener( Loader3DEvent.LOAD_SUCCESS, 
handler_loadSuccess ); 
var parser:Obj = new Obj(); 
loader.loadGeometry( "assets/objects/Test.obj", parser ); 

private function handler_loadSuccess( event:Loader3DEvent ):void 
{ 
        trace( "Success" ); 
        mat = new ColorMaterial( 0xFFFFFF ); 
        var mesh:Mesh = event.loader.handle as Mesh; 
        mesh.material = mat; 
        mesh.scale( 40 ) 
        mesh.x = 300; 
        viewport.scene.addChild( mesh ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I solved this by applying the material to all subfaces.